# 90s (or earlier) book: humanity split between 3 factions (China, America, Russia) which colonized space, and have telepaths/telekinetics individuals

Tags: story-identification, books

It's been gnawing on my brain for the past 20 years... I love Scifi/Fantasy books and pretty much read all of Isaac Asimov and Piers Anthony books. I hope the collective SciFi mind can help me out:

The premise of the books is that the humans have colonized the galaxy. Humanity was, however, broken up into 3 factions. The Chinese, Americans and Russians (I think) ended up as the primary groups. Each group has its own sectors of the galaxy, and there is a lot of distrust and there are skirmishes (I'm not sure if they were at war).

During this time there were people with mutant powers. Powers such as telepathy and telekinesis. There were also people who were Null (not affected by telepathic powers). I also remember that individuals had tattoos or markings that signify, either their faction or their powers (I'm not sure)

The whole story is that each faction had a military group or squad after SOMETHING in a tower/building. The book would jump from the perspective of faction to faction to tell the story. Each faction, had a protagonist and would have their own storyline. There was one part where 2 of the factions had a firefight: faction A detected that faction B had a telepath scanning their tactics. When the Null person found out, she (I remember that she was a she) changed the settings of the blasters of her fellow soldiers to a stun/spread mode. So when they opened fire, they where able to hit several Faction B people and either advance or retreat to the tower/building.

I kind of remember that the book title had the word "Three" in it. Somehow I thought it went along the lines of "The Three Towers". Also the cover was a 70's dark color theme with a soldier looking towards a tower or building.

Comment: You mention "books". Was this part of a series?

Comment: I don't think so.  I borrowed it from a public library but had to return it before I finished.  I do not believe it was a 3rd book in a series but could be wrong.

Comment: Could it be [Null-A Three](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3422614-null-a-three?from_search=true)?

Comment: Possibly the CoDominium series by Pournelle?

Comment: The CoDominium was US and Russia, but they weren't in separate sectors but mixed together as the new rulers.  China wasn't really involved.

Comment: I checked out Null-A Three but no dice.  CoDominium doesn't seem to have Telepath or Telekenisis powers incorporated in the story.   Also I remember that humans was scattered among the factions with aliens. The more I think about it the factions were more divided by philosophy. I think is was a Militaristic, Economic and Religious...  I can also recall a scout ship finding this building or tower in the beginning of the book.  Kinda like a "We found an amazing once in a Lifetime discovery"

Comment: This sounds more like Piers Anthony than Isaac Asimov.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could this be *The Quintara Marathon* series by Jack L. Chalker?  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_L._Chalker):

- *The Demons at Rainbow Bridge*, Ace-Putnam's, hardcover, September, 1989 (ISBN 0-441-69992-8)
- *The Run to Chaos Keep*, Ace-Putnam's, May, 1991 (ISBN 0-441-69348-2)
- *The Ninety Trillion Fausts* (a.k.a. *90 Trillion Fausts*), Ace-Putnam's, October 1991 (ISBN 0-441-58103-X)

---

- humans spread throughout the galaxy, but are caught by three interstellar superpowers in the galaxy.  Humans therefore have no "home", but are living amongst the other alien races.
- one protagonist is a powerful telepath, but has one finger on one of his hands extensively tattooed to show his telepathic nature, by law.
- archeologists discover a pair of unknown aliens in a tomb; aliens awaken, broadcast a telepathic interstellar message that gets the three superpowers interested, and then disappear down a wormhole/tesseract
- some of the groups assigned by the superpowers are just whomever was closest, including slavers with a female slave/slaver protagonist.  Others included a machine intelligence, near-indestructible dwarf, created faunlike female, etc.
- story evolves into chasing the demons and learning about their physical and metaphysical nature as **real** demons, including the use of hexagrams for instantaneous teleport
- one of the battles between the superpower teams sounds like your battle vs. the telepath in one of the teams
- chasing the demons goes across several unknown planets and regions, trying to prevent these "forerunners" from waking up their entire demon race
- story ends with a few survivors of the three groups acquiring "angel"-like powers, stopping the traitors on their teams, and stopping the demons

Comment: You ARE AWESOME!!!  I found a 3 chapter snippet online and BAM right on the forehead!  You my friend just answered my 20 year old question!  I'm headed to Half.com to see if it's available.  The great Internet collective ROCKS!